# network adapter not listed in my virtualbox vm

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtualbox, opensuse

I am trying to SSH into a virtual machine I have set up in virtual box from my Windows 7 host machine. I would like to make several development machines and `ssh` into them from my host machine, as well as `ping` them and so on. Inside of virtualbox, I have my VM selected (openSUSE 12.3) and I right click and go to settings, select the network tab, enable adapter 2 with these settings:

[image]

When I spin up the machine and run the `ifconfig` command, I do not see the adapter 2 settings. Here is what I get:

[image]

You can see there is not `eth1` listed. From what I understand, I need the IP address of the `eth1` network adapter to `ssh` into the machine. Is this not the correct process to add this adapter inside a virtualbox VM?

### **EDIT**

`dmesg | grep e1000`:

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using bridged networking with your VMs? This way they would appear in your LAN, and you wouldn't need two interfaces to every VM for separate host / Internet access.

Comment: Is the `Adapter type` the same both on Adapter 1 / Adapter 2? What is the output of `dmesg | grep e1000` in the VM?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen No, there is no reason I'm not doing that. I'm not aware of the pros/cons of using either.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Please see my edit. Adapter 1 is `NAT`.

Comment: I would switch Adapter 1 to Bridged mode and disable Adapter 2. This is the easiest way to achieve your goal, assuming that you have a LAN set up with a DHCP server that can provide configuration to your VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your Virtualbox setup offhand. I have the same setup with an Ubuntu VM, and it works fine. I believe the issue is that the OS running inside the guest has to see both network cards and set up both interfaces. Some versions of Linux will do that automatically, and some won't.

For example, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/virtualbox-two-network-interfaces-nat-and-host-only-ones-in-a-debian-guest-on) is a question on the Unix stackexchange from someone having this problem on Debian. In that case, he had to manually add a line to a config file to enable the second network interface.

Unfortunately, I can't give you specific instructions for OpenSUSE. [This page](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_manconf.html) appears to be SUSE's documentation on the subject (and you can see the link for using YaST on the left side). It looks like you should be able to configure the interface from YaST. Alternately, it might be necessary to edit some `ifcfg-*` files in the directory `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Comment: I agree, the problem here is that the other network interface isn't configured inside the guest OS.

Comment: The problem was that the interface was not configured automatically. I was able to configure it through `network devices` in yast. Thank you.